# Error during importing Angular SubProject

Tags: angular

Im following this tutorial to add a sub-project to my main project.

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

I create the subproject with: ng generate application dashboard3 --routing

I modified app.module.ts of dashboard3 subproject as in tutorial:

```
//app.component.ts <- dashboard3 subproject
import { Component, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

const providers = []

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class Dashboard3AppComponent{
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: Dashboard3AppComponent,
      providers: providers
    }
  }
}

//app.module.ts <- dashboard3 subproject
import { BrowserModule }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }                   from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule }           from './app-routing.module';

import { DashSoftwareSettingsComponent } from './settings/dash-software-settings.component';

const providers = []

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashSoftwareSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    DashSoftwareSettingsComponent
  ],
  providers: providers,
  bootstrap: []
})
export class Dashboard3AppComponent { }
```

In main app, I tried to import the subproject:

```
//DASHBOARD 3
import { Dashboard3AppComponent }           from 'projects/dashboard3/src/app/app.component';

...

imports: [
           ... 
            Dashboard3AppComponent.forRoot()
         ]
```

I got this error in my frontend console:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```